# how to stop people giving a thumbs up twice on a web page

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

im making a site thats a news/blog kind of site where people can leave comments to the posts that are made. then logged in users are able to give a comment a thumb up or down. it works fine at the moment i click the thumb and it uses ajax to add the count to the database and update the number and it also stops the person from being able to click the thumb again but if you press f5 to refresh the page you can click the thumb up again. how can i stop this from happening?
adding this to a database is an option i was thinking of but the site needs to be able to handle lots of comments and users there could be thousands of thumbs made to comments since its an easy action to perform the database table would be huge after a short amount of time which would surely slow down page loads since it will be querying a massively long table every time you view a page with comments.

currently i keep count of the thumbs up and down in the comment table so it querys the comments table and will display the numbers. are you suggesting i add a new table that contains userid and a commentid if someone makes a thumb up so i can query that table and if there is a row where userid == the logged in user and commentid == the comment dont allow? if so this is the thought i had on how to do it but as i said above it will lead to a massive table that will surely slow down the loading of the page

Comment: Keep the `count` you're using but also store the user that performed the `thumb up` and make sure to not allow it a second time.

Comment: it is a validation that on thumbs up/down you have to check whether this user has already voted or not and accordingly take next step ...THUMBS UP..!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, you need to add it to the database.  You can't keep track of the fact that it happened without storing the information!  You are already allowing comments on your site.  Think how much more space is required for a comment than a thumbs up.  Yes, your database might get big, but the solution to that is having a database that's well designed and powerful enough for your site!

Comment: It should be a pretty fast DB call if all you do is store a list of `comment-id` and `user-id` for a thumbs up. All you'd have to do is check if the `user-id` is in that table for that `comment-id` already...if so, don't allow them

Comment: If you don't want to expand your database you can keep that information in the cookies - not brilliant (as users can delete their cookies), but a quick solution

Comment: A couple of thousand thumb-up's is peanuts for a decent database. Even a couple of million shouldn't be any problem if you designed your database correctly

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is when you load the comments also load if that user has already casted a vote on each of them, disable the thumb up button if that user already voted.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt store the click as a simple counter but store the actual event

Create a seperate table called 'clicklog' or something and add the fields like `userid`, `commentid`, `IsThumbsUp`. Then in your ajax page you can add the thumbs up to this table (`IsThumbsUp` is a boolean. True for thumbsup and false for thumbs down.

then instead of using something like `SELECT comment, thumbsUp, thumbsDown` you could use

```
SELECT id, comment,
       (SELECT count(commentid) FROM clicklog WHERE commentID=id AND IsThumbsUp=1) AS thumbsUp,
       (SELECT count(commentid) FROM clicklog WHERE commentID=id AND IsThumbsUp=0) AS thumbsDown
FROM comments
```

And also in your AJAX page you can check if the user has voted before. If he has, dont allow it. Or even better. When he has voted UP, he can change it to vote DOWN (change the IsThumbsUp from 1 to 0) or visa versa.

Just make sure each user only has one connection with commentid and userid.

Also make sure you put an index on the fields in clicklog to get the information quickly. I'd put the primary key on `commentid` and `userid` combined and then a seperate index on `commentid` and `IsThumbsUp` combined